# Trying to incorporate svg circle within a d3 donut

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I am trying to add a SVG circle within my d3 donut. My SVG circle displays the percentage as a fill of circle, for example, if the D3 donut is at 50%, the SVG will show 50% filled. I want to put the SVG circle within the inside of my D3 donut.

Here is my codepen for this. http://codepen.io/iamsok/pen/MwdPpx

```
class ProgressWheel {
  constructor(patient, steps, container){
    this._patient = patient;
    this._steps = steps;
    this.$container = $(container);

    var τ = 2 * Math.PI,
    width = this.$container.width(),
    height = this.$container.height(),
    innerRadius = Math.min(width,height)/4,
    //innerRadius = (outerRadius/4)*3,
    fontSize = (Math.min(width,height)/4);
    var tooltip = d3.select(".tooltip");
    var status = {
      haveNot: 0,
      taken: 1,
      ignored: 2
    }

    var daysProgress = patient.progress
    var percentComplete = Math.round(_.countBy(daysProgress)[status.taken] / daysProgress.length * 100); 

    var participation = 100;
    var color = ["#CCC", "#FDAD42", "#EFD8B5"];

    var pie = d3.layout.pie()
      .value(function(d) { return 1; })
      .sort(null);

    var arc = d3.svg.arc();

    var svg = d3.select(container).append("svg")
      .attr("width", '100%')
      .attr("height", '100%')
      .attr('viewBox','0 0 '+Math.min(width,height) +' '+Math.min(width,height) )
      .attr('preserveAspectRatio','xMinYMin')
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" +  width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

    var innerCircle = d3.select("svg")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", 250)
      .attr("height", 250);

    var grad = innerCircle.append("defs")
      .append("linearGradient").attr("id", "grad")
      .attr("x1", "0%").attr("x2", "0%").attr("y1", "100%").attr("y2", "0%");
      grad.append("stop").attr("offset", percentComplete + "%").style("stop-color", "lightblue");
      grad.append("stop").attr("offset", percentComplete + "%").style("stop-color", "white");

    innerCircle.append("circle")
     .attr("r", 40)
     .attr("cx", 70)
     .attr("cy", 70)
     .style("stroke", "black")
     .style("fill", "url(#grad)");

    var gs = svg.selectAll(".arc")
      .data(pie(daysProgress))
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc");

    var path = gs.append("path")
     .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color[d.data]; })
     .attr("d", function(d, i, j) { return arc.innerRadius(innerRadius+(20*j)).outerRadius(innerRadius+20+(20*j))(d); })
     .attr("class", function(d, i, j) { if (i>=participation && j<1) return "passed" ; })

    svg.append("text")
      .attr("dy", "0.5em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("class", "inner-circle")
      .attr("fill", "#36454f")
      .text(Math.round(_.countBy(daysProgress)[status.taken] / daysProgress.length * 100) + "%");
}
}


    var patient = {progress: [0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]}

    var progressWheel = new ProgressWheel(patient, 14, '.chart-container' )
```

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: Im trying to get the svg circle(blue fill) to sit inside of the D3 donut.  So im trying to append an svg into an svg and that is a no-no. I have an svg circle that represents the percentage of participation level from my d3 donut. Im trying to get the svg circle to sit inside the d3 donut, but because both are svgs it can’t be done. I need to make both into a single svg in order for it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put the d3 donut and inner circle under the same svg so that they have the same coordinate system.

Check out here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ojbQNE

```
Modified code is on codepen
```

Comment: hahah i feel so stupid!!! had all the necessary components just couldnt put the puzzle together :( thank you so much for your help